# How do I run a sudo command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, sudo, shell

I'm trying to create shortcut keys for some commonly used sudo shell commands (for example, having `C-c s` run `(shell-command "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart")`).

I tried using a straight-up shell-command call as above, but it just outputs the following to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer:

```
[sudo] password for Inaimathi:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for Inaimathi:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for Inaimathi:
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

It doesn't actually ask for a password. I don't want to have to start up Emacs using `sudo emacs`, but I guess that's an option if nothing else will work.

The ideal solution would be a function from within Emacs (as opposed to OS jiggery-pokery to change the behaviour of the shell or the `sudo` command). Something like `(sudo-shell-command "dostuff")`, or `(with-password-prompt (shell-command "sudo dostuff"))`.

Comment: Related (near duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95631/open-a-file-with-su-sudo-inside-emacs and the vote to migrate to Super User may be correct. @Inaimathi: If this is closely tied to programming, now would be a good time to explain why, or this questions will likely be moved to a more suitable site.

Comment: Given that the OP is trying to bind some elisp to a key this is programmy enough for me.

Comment: Restructured question to alleviate some of the confusion.

Comment: You don't use this. You could just open the file with TRAMP, `/sudo::/etc/init.d/apaches2` and then start a shell from that file with `M-x shell`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
(shell-command (concat "echo " (shell-quote-argument (read-passwd "Password? "))
                       " | sudo -S your_command_here"))
```

Comment: Perfect. In other words, I could easily do something like `(defun sudo-shell-command (command) (shell-command (concat "echo " (read-passwd "Password: ") " | sudo -S " command)))`. Much better than actually writing the password in source-code too.

Answer (score 14):

I frequently call commands from Emacs like `aptitude update`. [scottfrazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17637/scottfrazer)'s solution might not be as useful.  Synchronous commands make me wait for a long time, and if you execute an unsupported program (for example, `aptitude`, which uses [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)), you will hang up Emacs (<kbd>C-g</kbd> won't help), and CPU load will be 100%. Changing to `async-shell-command` solves this.

But it also introduces a new problem. If your command fails, your password will end up in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
echo PASSWORD | sudo -S aptitude: exited abnormally with code 1.
```

That's why i propose the following solution:

```
(defun sudo-shell-command (command)
  (interactive "MShell command (root): ")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (cd "/sudo::/")
    (async-shell-command command)))
```

Here "M" in `interactive` prompts for program name in minibuffer, `with-temp-buffer` creates a sham buffer, in which we change directory to `/sudo::/` to use TRAMP for sudo prompt.

This is the solution by David Kastrup from [sudo command with minibuffer password prompt @ gnu.emacs.help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/fXxnXc3v-pM).

Note, you still shouldn't call `aptitude` directly, otherwise the subprocess will be there forever, until you send `sudo pkill aptitude`.

Read on [shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html#Single-Shell) and [processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes) in manual.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I think it should be marked as the best.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running emacs22 or later, you can just start up a shell from emacs and run your sudo command there. It'll automatically pull you into the minibuffer window for your password:

```
M-x shell
sudo whoami
```

This should just ask for your password down at the bottom of the screen (*without* displaying it).

Comment: This is the easiest solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Workaround** (rather than an emacs solution):

Set up a ssh key pair so that no password is necessary.

Procedure:

1. run `ssh-keygen` to generate a pair of keys. Give them a useful name to keep them sorted out from all the others you'll make once you get use to this
2. Copy the *public* one to `$HOME/.ssh` for the *receiving* account
3. Keep the *private* one in `$HOME/.ssh` of the sending account (you could copy it to multiple sending accounts, but it might be better to make a separate keypair for every incoming machine)
4. edit `$HOME/.ssh/config` on the sending machine to tell ssh what key to use
5. Profit

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` attempts to open the terminal device (tty) to read the password. Your emacs process may not have a controlling terminal. `sudo -S` tells it to use the standard input for a password which should be coming from emacs.

Comment: `(shell-command "sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 restart")` does the same thing (ie. it tries an arbitrary password 3 times, and sends the 3 unsuccessful attempts to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer.

Comment: And `(shell-command "echo password | sudo -S /etc/init.d/apache2 restart")`? (Not that it's a good solution to encode the password in the command.)

Comment: Yeah. I wouldn't want my root password in my code somewhere. That sounds like it might be worse than running `sudo emacs`. +1 for suggesting the -S approach (even if I did misunderstand it at first)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Scott's answer above is vastly preferable to this hack. Use that.

A possible solution:

I found out that setting a default password-asking utility solves this problem.

What I had to do is add `Defaults:ALL    askpass=/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass` to my `/etc/sudoers` file (using `sudo visudo`, obviously).

Eval-ing `(shell-command "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart")` now prompts me for a password instead of trying to guess it unsuccessfully.

I'm not accepting this answer unless it becomes clear that there's no better solution; ideally I'd like something that solves the problem internally to Emacs instead of requiring you to poke around your `/etc` directory.

Comment: Better yet, if you have sudoers control, you can set it up so *you* are not prompted for a password for these programs that you run frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses `start-process`, `set-process-filter`, and `set-process-sentinel`.  Although this is an elaborate minimal working example, a similar approach is used all the time when there are known STRINGS output by a running process that require input from the user (or programmatically inputting a preprogrammed response to an inquiry from the running process).  It could be a password, a username, a yes / no question, etc.  The trick is to do a little testing while setting up the function to ascertain what STRING needs to be matched with a REGEXP.  This example was written up on Ubuntu 20.04 running `sudo` with the `ls` command.  The STRING that needs to be matched is:  `[sudo] password for lawlist:`  with a space following the colon, and with my username being `lawlist`.  Now, the REGEXP could have been something as simple as `"password"`, but I wanted to be more specific as a matter of personal preference so that I understand (in the future) what was going when the code was written.  The process-filter is normally a separate function, but it can also be included in `let`-bound form.  When debugging while writing up the code, it may sometimes be necessary to kill a running process using something like `M-x list-processes` to inspect what is going on.  It may also be helpful to uncomment the DEBUGGING message in the process-filter.

```lisp
(let ((sudo-process-filter
        (lambda (proc string)
          ;;; DEBUGGING:
          ;;  (message "STRING: `%s`" string)
          (cond
            ((string-match "^\\[sudo\\] password for lawlist: $" string)
              (let ((password (read-passwd "PWD:  ")))
                (process-send-string proc (concat password "\n"))))
            (t
              (with-current-buffer (messages-buffer)
                (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
                  (goto-char (point-max))
                  (when (not (bolp))
                    (insert "\n"))
                  (insert string)
                  (when (not (bolp))
                    (insert "\n"))))))))
      (msg-success "SUCCESS!")
      (msg-failure "FAILURE!"))
  (start-process "ls-proc-name" nil "sudo" "-S" "ls" "-la")
  (set-process-filter (get-process "ls-proc-name")
                      (symbol-value 'sudo-process-filter))
  (set-process-sentinel
    (get-process "ls-proc-name")
    ;;; To penetrate the lambda expression with a let-bound variable, we use a
    ;;; backtick / comma combination.  This obviates the need for lexical binding.
    `(lambda (p e)
      (if (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
         (message "%s" ,msg-success)
         (message "%s" ,msg-failure)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to start nmap from emacs as root,

http://nakkaya.com/sudoEl.markdown

Comment: That link appears dead. Is there somewhere we can see it?