# How to run Emacs commands with sudo outside a shell?

Tags: emacs, command, sudo, tramp

I know how to open/edit files in Emacs as root with sudo, using Tramp. I wonder if there is a way to run Emacs commands with sudo too, without opening a shell?

Something like:

sudo M-x find-name-dired

or

M-x sudo find-name-dired

for example.

Comment: This question seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95631/open-a-file-with-su-sudo-inside-emacs

Answer (score 5):

If your command involves some path on the filesystem it is possible to take advantage of tramp like this: `M-x find-name-dired RET /sudo::/your/path`.

Comment: Thanks, that is already half the solution I was looking for, and helps a lot. Maybe the other half doesn't exist? I leave the question open for a while ...