# emacs key commands different in Windows and Linux?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to finally bite the bullet and learn emacs. Mainly so that I am comfortable editing files on a server through ssh. So I installed emacs on Windows in order practice. Right away I noticed this difference: when I press `ctrl - rightarrow` on windows, the cursor jumps to the next work. When I do this in emacs on the server, the cursor moves to the next character only. I believe the latter is the "normal" behaviour (`M - rightarrow` will jump to the next word in both versions). How can I get my windows emacs to behave exactly like the one on the server? I don't want to learn habits on windows that won't carry over to the server.

Comment: This is not programmjng-related, really; but additiinakky, it is too broad, and I have nominated for  closure for that reason. Your question depends on the terminal software, which terminal emulation modes it offers, how compatible they are with the terminal driver of the remote server, as well as of course the Emacs version and how you are  invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

You mention server, I assume you are connecting to it over SSH? It is very likely that something over the route steals modifiers off your C-arrow movements.

If this is the case, try to edit your files *locally*. Here's how: [How can I use Emacs tramp to ssh to a remote host and edit a file as another user on an ad-hoc basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832837/how-can-i-use-emacs-tramp-to-ssh-to-a-remote-host-and-edit-a-file-as-another-use)